# PHP access Array

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm having this response which I can access till a certain point :

```
{
  - response : {
     id:"xxx",
     ...
     - tags : {
       - 10000: {
           id:"10000",
           word: "ok"
         }
     }
   }
}
```

i can access with no problem $elem->response->tags but I have no ideea how to access to the word propriety to get "ok"

Thank you

Comment: `$elem->response->tags->{'1000'}->word`

Comment: It doesnt work unfortunatelly

Comment: fortunately it works, you just need to bring more attention to it and not blindly copy-paste something other people propose. http://ideone.com/oRqJVa

Comment: Maybe it works with other examples Zerkms ... But for my example I can assure you it doesnt work

Comment: for the example you provided it works. I provided a link with purpose. Sorry, we cannot read your mind - if it does not work for some other data - then it's just you who cannot write the code.

Comment: Yes you're right it works ... I've seen it with var_dump ... My problem was somewhere else ... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$elem->response->tags->{1000}->word
```

or

```
$key = 1000;
$elem->response->tags->$key->word
```

or (quite ugly, not sure if working). Definitely not working if it ain't the first key

```
$key = reset((array) $elem->response->tags);
$key->word
```

Comment: I tryed all 3 methods with 10000 instead of 1000 as it should be on my code and the API gives me all the time "There was an error"

Comment: So if i'm trying to access $elem->response->tags I'll always get :
- tags : {
       - 10000: {
           id:"10000",
           word: "ok"
         }
     }

but I just need to have that word value

Comment: What's the full object/string then?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
$elem->response->tags->[1000]->word
```

Answer (score 0):

The key `10000` is not a valid identifier. So you can not write it directly in the source, it will be mistaken as the number. On a second note you structure is an object (It might be \stdClass), not an array.

Instances of stdClass are traversable and can be cast into an array:

```
$object = new \stdClass();
$object->property = 'test';
var_dump((array)$object);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["property"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

In an array, you provide the keys as values, so the syntax conflict is not here. On an object you need to use a special syntax - use {} to mark the identifier.

```
$json = json_decode(
  json_encode(
    array('10000' => 'test')
  )
);

var_dump($json->{'10000'});
```

Output:

```
string(4) "test"
```

In you case that would be:

```
$elem->response->tags->{'10000'}->word
```

Comment: So the structure I've given is taken from PSTMAN REST Client ... The 10000 is there because that is the response from the API

Comment: That's ok, it is just a syntax problem for the parser if you try to use it as an property/variable name. It thinks the 10000 is a number - with {} you make it clear for the parser how he should parse it.